# How to backup Blender startup file?

Tags: startup-file

I recently changed my computer. So I opened the blender, and I have so many custom parts that I want to transfer the startup backup file to a new computer.
I don't know the location of the startup file, but I couldn't find it.

So, how can I bring the startup file at new computer

Comment: what kind of startup file?

Comment: You can just save that file

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to start a new scene and then save it as a file.  Copy that file to the new computer. When you're ready open that file on the new computer and then use the file menu to "Save Startup file".

[image: Save startup file]